# why ExecutorService is not getting frequently executed

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a method which i need to update frequently for every some specific time , so i was testing java ExecutorService , but my method is not getting frequently updated , could you please tell me why ?

These are my classes

FutureTask.java

```
package com;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class FutureTask {
    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private static FutureTask _instance = new FutureTask();

    public static FutureTask getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    private static int timoutsec = 15;

    public Object submiteTask(final Object obj, final Method method,
            final Object[] params) throws Exception {
        return submiteTask(obj, method, params, -1);
    }

    public Object submiteTask(final Object obj, final Method method,
            final Object[] params, int timeoutSeconds) throws Exception {
        if (null != obj && method != null) {
            Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
                public Object call() {
                    try {
                        method.setAccessible(true);
                        Object resultObj = method.invoke(obj, params);
                        return resultObj;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
            try {
                Object result = null;
                if (timeoutSeconds < 0) {
                    result = future.get(timoutsec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } else {
                    result = future.get(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                return result;
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                future.cancel(true);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            FutureTask.getInstance().submiteTask(
                    new TestingFutureTaskUtil(),
                    TestingFutureTaskUtil.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                            "updateMethodCalled",
                            new Class<?>[] { String.class }),
                    new Object[] { "UBSC!OC1010" }, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**TestingFutureTaskUtil.java**

```
package com;

public class TestingFutureTaskUtil {

    public void updateMethodCalled(String symbol) {

        System.out.println("updateMethodCalled" + symbol);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: That won't solve your issue but I suggest renaming your `FutureTask` class to something else. That is already the name of a class in the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense as it's written. Generally, you'd use an `ExecutorService` when you want to handle task execution on separate threads. In this case, you're adding a task to an `ExecutorService` but blocking your main thread until it completes. Surely that's not what you're trying to do? This is entirely defeating the purpose of the Executor

Comment: @ColinMorelli , agreed with your comment , in my production code it is as it is you mentioned , but to represent the scenario i replicated the sample using a simple Standalone program .

Comment: use SchedulerExecutorService

Comment: I see you are trying to use the singleton pattern. In fact, your code is not thread safe! if two different threads got "the" instance of the class, you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a normal ExecutorService. It doesn't allow to schedule tasks. You need to use a ScheduledExecutorService.

You need to change the following:

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);
```

and:

```
Future<Object> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, timeoutSeconds, timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now the task will be executed every "timeoutSeconds" Seconds. Afterwards you can return the ScheduledFuture and can get the updated values from it.

Maybe it is just because of the example but I would create an callable outside and hand that to FutureTask. Than you don't need Reflection. Also the way you doing an asynchronous call is wrong because the calling thread always waits for the computation to finish. Therefore, you don't gain any benefits from the running the method in an other thread. Maybe you need to rethink the whole design of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You only submit one job, so updateMethodCalled is only called once.

Comment: @Kiran I think you want a `java.util.Timer` if you're trying to run this method on a certain interval

Comment: Don't use the java.util.Timer Class for this purpose. Each timer runs in seperate Thread and you could end up with hundreds/thousends of threads which do nothing 99,99% of the time. Depends on the application of course.